# Merging two similar multidimensional arrays into one

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$arr1 = array (
    array (
        array (
            'correct' => FALSE,
            'answer' => 'false answer1'
        ),  
        array (
            'correct' => FALSE,
            'answer' => 'false answer2'
        ),  
        array (
            'correct' => FALSE,
            'answer' => 'false answer3'
        )   
    ));
```

And this array:

```
$arr2 = array (
    array ( 
        array (
            'correct' => TRUE,
            'answer' => 'correct answer'
        )   
    ));
```

I want the output to be:

```
$output = array (
    array (
        array (
            'correct' => FALSE,
            'answer' => 'false answer1'
        ),
        array (
            'correct' => FALSE,
            'answer' => 'false answer2'
        ),
        array (
            'correct' => FALSE,
            'answer' => 'false answer3'
        ),                  
        array (
            'correct' => TRUE,
            'answer' => 'correct answer'
        )
    ));
```

I tried `using array_merge`, `array_merge_recursive`, but it merges it not how i want it to (it just added the values at the bottom instead of placing them into each array correctly). I also saw similar questions to this, but it didnt help me (still merges the values at the bottom and not how i want them to).

Any suggestions?

Comment: It always merges at the bottom, do you want to sort the array by a certain way?

Comment: No, what i ment was, for me it adds new array columns `[1] - [0][1][2]; [2] - [3]`, and i want it to be like so - `[1] - [0][1][2][3]`. Sorry i dont know how to explain myself properly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
array_merge($arr1[0], $arr2[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$array[] = array_merge($arr1[0],$arr2[0]);
print_r($array);
```

## Codepad

## Output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [correct] => 
                [answer] => false answer1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [correct] => 
                [answer] => false answer2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [correct] => 
                [answer] => false answer3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [correct] => 1
                [answer] => correct answer
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, Great answer!!! Very well formatted & give demo in codepad. You rock bro!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  $arr1= array (
                array (
                        array (
                                  'correct' => FALSE,
                                  'answer' => 'false answer1'
                        ),
                        array (
                                  'correct' => FALSE,
                                  'answer' => 'false answer2'
                        ),
                        array (
                                  'correct' => FALSE,
                                  'answer' => 'false answer3'
                        )
                )
                );
      $arr2= array (
                    array ( 
                        array (
                                  'correct' => TRUE,
                                  'answer' => 'correct answer'
                        )
                )
                );  

      $result=array(array_merge($arr1[0],$arr2[0]));
      print_r($result);
```

output

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [correct] => 
                [answer] => false answer1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [correct] => 
                [answer] => false answer2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [correct] => 
                [answer] => false answer3
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [correct] => 1
                [answer] => correct answer
            )

    )

 )
```